# jQuery Validation - Phone US Submit on success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Okay, so I basically just used the example for the jquery validation phone US plugin from the Jquery site - it looks to be working (there have been some posts where it isn't).

My question, is how do I actually "submit" the form upon success? I am obviously fairly new to jQuery, and Javascript in general. With the normal jQuery validation without the plugin, it looks fairly straightforward - but I'm not sure exactly how to do it. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/lib/jquery.delegate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});;
</script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");

$("#testinput").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      phoneUS: true
    }
  }
});

  });
  </script>
  <style>#field { margin-left: .5em; float: left; }
    #field, label { float: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small; }
    br { clear: both; }
    input { border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: .5em;  }
    input.error { border: 1px solid red; }
    label.error {
        background: url('http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/demo/images/unchecked.gif') no-repeat;
        padding-left: 16px;
        margin-left: .3em;
    }
    label.valid {
        background: url('http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/demo/images/checked.gif') no-repeat;
        display: block;
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form id="testinput" action="http://transworldmx.com">
  <label for="field">Required, us phone number: </label>
  <input class="left" id="field" name="field" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code just checks that the phone number is a phone number (through a regex) and makes sure the field is required. Once these rules are applied, just click on the "Validate!" button to submit your form. You will need some server-side script (like PHP) to take care of the form datas though.

Comment: I have the back end configured.. but for some reason, when I click "submit" it only displays the check mark image saying it has validated, it does not continue to the action I have set on the form. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If validation passes, the form should submit automatically. If it doesn't, then either validation fails, or there is some JavaScript error... Use FireBug or IE development tools (F12) to troubleshoot!

Comment: Again, since I don't know too much about jquery or javascript (only basics, and how to 'copy' examples) - I am still not getting the expected results of the form being submitted upon success. I am not getting any errors via firebug either.

I currently have no method set for the form, and just an arbitrary page set as the action, I would imagine that i would still get a 'page not found' or something if the validation completed, but nothing, it just stays on the same page with the check mark displayed for having the correct format.

Comment: I copied your code into my project, and I am getting errors that these libraries on CDN don't exist. Don't know why you would not get an error in firebug, but cut and paste the name into your browser - and you will get 404. Once I pointed to the local libraries - everything works as it supposed to

Comment: I see what you mean, I got the 404 - where do I get the code for the local library? I am not even able to find a download link for the plugin on the site anywhere?

Comment: I ended up using this url:
[link](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/additional-methods.js)

I still am getting the error that the validator is undefined. How were you able to get this to work? May I see what you did?

Comment: I took your code verbatim, then changed the libraries to point to local copies, and changed the action to point to something meaningful. That's it, and it works. My IDE is MS Visual Studio, and both jquery and jquery.validate are installed automatically - but you can download them from jquery site. It certainly looks like you are chasing red herring - your real problem is infrastructure setup, not your code!

Comment: Weird... I set debug to false (under validator.setDefaults()) and it works perfectly.